# How do you run a Python file in HTML?

Tags: python, html, django, virtualenv

A while ago, I created some mini games with Python. And now i'm working with HTML. I know how to link a CSS file to an HTML file. But I do not know how to link a Python file to some words in an HTML file.

I have tried to directly href it to my Python file like this:

```
<a href="Alien Invasion\Main\Alien Invasion.py">Play the Game</a>
```

This is what I've got so far

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'webinfos/style.css' %}">
    <ul>
<li><a>Home</a></li>        
<li><a>Alien Invasion</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a>Explanation of Game</a></li>
    <li><a>How to play</a></li>
    <li><a>Origin</a></li>
    <li><a>Play the Game</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Crossy Road</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a>Explanation of Game</a></li>
    <li><a>How to play</a></li>
    <li><a>Origin</a></li>
    <li><a>Play the Game</a></li>
    </ul>       
</li>
<li><a>Classic Snake Game</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a>Tips&amp;Tricks</a></li>
    <li><a>Best Gameplays</a></li>
    <li><a>Funny Moments</a></li>
    <li><a>How to Play</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Other stuff</a></li>
</ul>


</html>
```

I expected it so that when I click on the words that are linked to the file, it runs the game. But instead, it shows:

Page not found (404)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: In Django you don't link the Python file, you link the route defined for your view.

Comment: But how will a Python game run in the browser?

Comment: Either use Pygame directly or use projects like Titanium or skulpt. But you can not make a web game in python. You have to use js or simply create it with C++ or Java.

Comment: I see that I can't run a python file in html directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into something called PyScript, they can also tap into the Python ecosystem, which has useful scientific modules such as NumPy, Matplotlib, and many more.

Comment: a link, an explanation, and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to run a python file in the browser in the way that you're doing it. If you really want to run scripts in a browser it's best to look up JavaScript.